# Compiling linux module : no build directory

Tags: kernel, compiling, virtualization

I try to compile a simple kernel module with a simple makefile.

```
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m := my_module.o

all: modules

modules modules_install clean help:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) $@
```

This is what I get when I try to compile :

```
root@vm:/home/my_modules# make
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0+/build M=/home/my_modules modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.10.0+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I saw in another post that I should get linux headers and a system link. So I tried without success.

```
root@vm:/home/my_modules# apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.10.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.10.0'
```

I am running these from a virtual machine.
How should I get the linux headers in order to compile my module ?

From outside my vm (I'm using a nfsroot), I can see that the build folder is not empty. From the vm perspective, it is empty.

```
johndoe@anywhere:~/workspace/linux$ ls /home/johndoe/rootfs/lib/modules/4.10.0+/build/
arch   certs   drivers   fs       init  kernel  Makefile  modules.builtin  Module.symvers  scripts   sound   System.map  virt     vmlinux.o
block  crypto  firmware  include  ipc   lib     mm        modules.order    net             security  source  usr         vmlinux
```

vm perspective :

```
root@vm:/home/my_modules# ls /lib/modules/4.10.0+/build 
/lib/modules/4.10.0+/build
root@vm:/home/my_modules# du /lib/modules/4.10.0+/build 
0   /lib/modules/4.10.0+/build
```

Why ?